# Not getting which assembly reference I need to add to remove red mark from FileSystemWatcher in c#

Tags: c#, text-files, filesystemwatcher, file-handling

I have a c# program which is using `FileSystemWatcher` to watch and get the lines. But my concern is that I am not getting which assembly reference I need to add to remove red error mark from the program ..

Here is my code..

```
public void File_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
        lock (this)
        {
            if (!this.bPaused)
            {
                bool bMoreData = false;

                // Read from current seek position to end of file
                byte[] bytesRead = new byte[this.iMaxBytes];
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.strFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                if (0 == this.iPreviousSeekPos)
                {
                    if (this.bReadFromStart)
                    {
                        if (null != this.BeginReadStart)
                        {
                            this.BeginReadStart(null, null);
                        }
                        this.bReadingFromStart = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fs.Length > this.iMaxBytes)
                        {
                            this.iPreviousSeekPos = fs.Length - this.iMaxBytes;
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.iPreviousSeekPos = (int)fs.Seek(this.iPreviousSeekPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int iNumBytes = fs.Read(bytesRead, 0, this.iMaxBytes);
                this.iPreviousSeekPos += iNumBytes;

                // If we haven't read all the data, then raise another event
                if (this.iPreviousSeekPos < fs.Length)
                {
                    bMoreData = true;
                }

                fs.Close();

                string strData = this.encoding.GetString(bytesRead);
                this.MoreData(this, strData);

                if (bMoreData)
                {
                    File_Changed(null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.bReadingFromStart)
                    {
                        this.bReadingFromStart = false;
                        if (null != this.EndReadStart)
                        {
                            this.EndReadStart(null, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting red underline marks in the following code snippets ..

```
if (!this.bPaused)
this.iMaxBytes
this.iPreviousSeekPos
this.bReadFromStart
```

Please guys help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: And the error messages are?

Comment: It doesn't look like a reference issue. You get the errors when you are calling `this`, meaning the members are missing from your own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and the symptoms you describe, it's likely that your class doesn't define the fields `bPaused`, `iMaxBytes`, `iPreviousSeekPos` and `bReadFromStart`.

In particular, it doesn't seem to be due to a reference issue.